# How i use css files in spring-boot - they seems to not load at all

Tags: css, spring-security

After implementing spring security - css files stop working.
I get response code 200, but when I try to look inside style.css I get HTML code instead. 
For past few days i try go use all solutions i found in web. - no succes.

I move my files to resources/static/css/ folder - don`t work.
i configure httpSecurity to give folder permision - not work,
i try to set all access to page - no authoristaion - still not work,

Html line

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/styles.css}" media="screen, projection">
```

http security config

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/css/styles.css", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

My resource structure
resuurces
-- static
----css
styles.css
...

I dont get any errors.
my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<html
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->

    <title>index</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js"
            integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js"
            integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/styles.css}" media="screen, projection">

</head>
<body>

INDEX

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div th:insert="fragments/sidemenu.html"></div>


    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <Welcomne sec:authentication="name"></Welcomne>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Popper.JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Side menu is loaded but without formating

I want to have working page with css formating, 
Actual page seems to loading but formating is gone.
I have no idea what to try  next.

Comment: Try removing static while referencing your css file in href attribute: th:href="@{/css/styles.css}".

Comment: Also you are not giving permission to your css files, if you have done it share your relevant configuration.

Comment: I add css lint to permitAll, - no effect

Comment: Have you tried overriding configure(WebSecurity) as well? I managed to get them in a similar project like this: @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**/**")
            .antMatchers("/css/**");
    }

Comment: NOpe, not working 

     @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**/**").antMatchers("/css/**");
    }